# How to draw Button class in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I know that libgdx has this `Button` class that seems so easy to use, but I wonder why the `draw` method is set protected?

In that case, how should I draw the button?

[Scene2d Button](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Button` is also an `Actor`.  So you would put it on the `Stage` and the framework would draw it.  [Here](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) is some more documentation on how this fits together.

Comment: Did you follow the link I posted?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d and https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui.

Answer (score 7):

I'm writing a libgdx tutorial for beginners. This post might be useful to you: [libgdx Tutorial: scene2d](http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/02/3-libgdx-tutorial-scene2d.html)

Answer (score 3):

Button is an Actor, so it is used with Stage. There is [official documentation](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d) for scene2d. Button is in scene2d.ui, which is a UI framework on top Stage, which is a general purpose 2D scene graph. There is no official documentation for scene2d.ui yet. You can see [UITest](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java) though.

Comment: Now official documentation for scene2dui. https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui